# celeryd insists on checking amqp when its configured to use redis

Tags: celery, django-celery

I am trying to run celerdy + redis in my setup.

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
CELERY_BIN="/home/snijsure/.virtualenvs/mtest/bin/celery"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/snijsure/work/mytest/"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="analytics.settings.local"
```

I have following in my base.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_BACKEND="redis"
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_USER = ""
BROKER_PASSWORD =""
BROKER_VHOST = "0"
REDIS_DB = 0
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES =  10
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER="djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

However when I start the celeryd using /etc/init.d/celerdy start

I see following messages in my log files

```
[2014-08-14 23:16:41,430: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds...
```

It seems like its trying to connect to amqp. Any ideas on why that is I have followed procedure outlined here

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html
I am running version  3.1.13 (Cipater)

What am I doing wrong?

-Subodh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you start you celery worker? I encounter this error once because I didn't start it right. You should add -A option when execute "celery worker" so that celery will connect to the broker you configured in your Celery Obj. Otherwise celery will try to connect the default broker.

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/default/celeryd file looks ok.

You are using djcelery, however. I'd recommend you drop that. If you look at the Django setup guide and example project you will notice that there are no longer any INSTALLED_APPS required for celery. It appears that djcelery is now only recommended if you want to use the Django SQL database as a backend.

- https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/examples/django/
- http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

I've just rebuilt against that pattern and I can confirm that it works ok, at least in terms of connecting to Redis rather than trying to use RabbitMQ (amqp).